# Cannot update nor install package on Arch, getting "empty reply from server" error

Tags: archlinux, update

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from va.us.mirror.archlinuxarm.org : Empty reply  from server
error: failed to update core (download library error)
extra                    428.7 KiB   121K/s 00:04 [######################] 100%
community                412.9 KiB   166K/s 00:02 [######################] 100%
alarm                      3.9 KiB  1667K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
aur                       11.1 KiB  1015K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
```

I can't update nor install any package. core.db fails to sync.

- I tried with Google DNS and OpenDNS, doesn't work.
- pacman.conf hasn't been touched. mirrorlist uses the default geo server but I have tried with each of the servers there.

Any idea what may cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: Weird. What happens when you do `curl http://va.us.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/`?

Comment: Is that the output from `pacman -Sy`?

Comment: Tried reflector? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reflector

Comment: weird, i woke up this morning and things work again! Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens if you're unfortunate enough to sync at exactly the same moment the server itself is being updated.

Usually if you wait a few minutes it will start working again when the server is again fully up to date, but it's possible your repeated attempts were causing some sort of caching of the incomplete file to take place.

The fact that it started working the following day makes perfect sense - by then the server was up to date and any caches would have been flushed and updated too.